# JSON.stringify optimization

Tags: javascript, json, memory, optimization

I'm working on a node.js application and I have some large objects I need to stringify before I save them into a database.
I know speed and resource usage are complementary, so I am wondering if a JSON.stringify implementation trading speed for a smaller memory usage exists.
Right now, given enough memory, the stringify operation is taking a few seconds. I don't mind if it would take 5 minutes to stringify it, as long as the memory usage is reduced.
So, do you know of any implementation trading speed for a smaller resource (especially memory) usage?

Comment: If it were files, I'd suggest a streamable JSON implementation, but since you're saving into a DB, you need the whole string in memory anyways

Comment: The stringified JSON itself is not that big (only a few tens of MB). The process of stringifiation on the other hand takes a lot of memory.